# Need some basic information regarding costmap_2D

Tags: navigation, costmap, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have some problems understanding the behaviour of the costmap_2D class.
First, I don't get how this class is started.

Right now I have a launch file, like in the navigation stack tutorial.

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="robot_mover" type="robot_mover" respawn="false" name="robot_mover" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find robot_mover)/cfg/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find robot_mover)/cfg/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find robot_mover)/cfg/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

where *robot_mover* is my package which shall be similar to the *move_base* package in the end.

And in my *robot_mover* package I have this code:

```
tf::TransformListener tf(ros::Duration(10));
costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS costmap("my_costmap", tf);
```

When I launch this either with

```
roslaunch robot_mover robot_mover.launch
```

or with

```
rosrun robot_mover robot_mover
```

I always get this warning:

> You have set map parameters, but also requested to use the static map. Your parameters will be overwritten by those given by the map server

Where do I request a static map here?
And why do I get this warning when I use rosrun?
I only set parameters in the yaml files which are called in the launch file, don't I?

I also start gmapping:

```
rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan
```

Does ROS mean the map from gmapping with this warning?

Don't know how else I could start this costmap.
I just wanna build a simple exploration algorithm that detects obstacles in front of my robot and therefore I wanted to use the grid with included obstacles.

Or shall I just ignore this warning?
Is it possible to get relevant data for obstacles out of the *costmap* variable of my class to compute the grid myself?

Hard to find anything in the ROS Wiki for this specific problem.

My yaml files look like that:

common:

```
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
footprint: [[-0.200, -0.350], [-0.200, 0.350], [0.200, 0.350], [0.200, -0.350]]
#robot_radius: ir_of_robot
inflation_radius: 0.55

observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor 

laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: /base_laser_link, data_type: LaserScan, topic:  base_scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

global:

```
global_costmap:
   global_frame: odom
   robot_base_frame: base_link
   update_frequency: 5.0
   static_map: false
```

local:

```
local_costmap:
   global_frame: odom
   robot_base_frame: base_link
   update_frequency: 5.0
   publish_frequency: 2.0
   static_map: false
   rolling_window: true
   width: 6.0
   height: 6.0
   resolution: 0.05
```

A bit much, but hopefully someone can help me!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33955/need-some-basic-information-regarding-costmap_2d/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2012-05-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, I believe this warning is due to the fact that in your global_costmap_params.yaml, you set `static_map` to `false`, but do not set `rolling_window` to `true`, and it defaults to `false`. You're essentially telling the costmap that it does not have a map or that it does not exist.

Second, this might just be an artifact of ROS Answers, but your parameters should be indented under the namespaces:

```
local_costmap:
    global_frame: odom
```

I'm assuming this is done, because I don't know if it would even run otherwise, but I just wanted to check.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2012-05-14**:
Oh, thanks! I will try that.  And yes, in my file it is indented.

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2012-05-15**:
Tried it now, and it doesn't help... Is there a rolling window option in the global costmap ?

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-05-15**:
The same rolling_window options exist for both costmaps (they're both costmap_2d, you just give each different parameters)

**Comment by [mkoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/309/mkoval/) on 2012-05-27**:
In the navigation documentation, I only see that `static_map` must be `false` if `rolling_window` is `true`. Is it also true that `rolling_window` must be `true` if `static_map` is `false`? If so, that might explain some of my problems (I was assuming that it initialize an empty map).